# multiple views in landscape and portrait

Tags: ipad, orientation, multiple-views

I want to implement my app in both landscape and portrait with two different views. When my app in landscape it shows one view and in portrait it shows the second view. It is possible. But when my app is loaded in portrait,it shows the unbutton control in actual place.Then i change orientation to landscape,button changes its position to opposite side and rotate the button so that my button title is also in opposite side. Please help me. And thank you for your helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're working with. Maybe this will help you:
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=79

**EDIT**: updated link - sorry no time to write an inline tut :(

Comment: It will work in iPhone. But its not working in iPad.The problem is when i load my app, firstly it show the landscapeView then i change my orientation to landscape it again shows the landscapeView. Then I change my orientation to portrait then it shows the portraitView and it works correctly. What is the reason for that. Help me please

Comment: @Manticore: Link is down.